# Summarizing GPS coordinates inside polygon in Google My Maps?

Tags: polygon, polygonize

I need to set up the most effective routes to visit different locations. I have several teams to visit the locations depending on where they are. I am given Latitude and Longitude of all the locations. What I am currently doing is upload all the locations from an Excel file to Google My Maps and give them a number sequence. The number sequence is in the same order as the list in the excel file and the GPS points are shown in the map as circles with the number inside, for example if there are 100 locations they are 100 circles with numbers from 1 to 100 each one representing an item from the list in Excel. After I have all the points represented in the map I decide how to organize them. If I have 100 locations and 5 teams, each team has to visit 20 locations. I then draw a polygon on top of the map and the GPS points like a fence to divide the points according to proximity, so when I finish I have 5 poligons with 20 locations each. Here comes the tricky part.. I haven´t found a way Google Maps export what GPS points are inside each polygon, so what I do is to write each number in a column in Excel and in the colum next to it I write the polygon it is inside, then with Vlookup I find in the original Excel file which polygon each number belongs to. This is very difficult when there are 500 or more GPS points.

Comment: Some possible keywords: location-allocation, traveling salesman problem (TSP). I don't know what capabilities Google My Maps has.